# Music that becomes flammable - What am I?

Tags: riddle, rhyme, anagram

This is an anagram styled riddle and the answer is a word.

> Be careful I'm dangerous, left how I'm read
>
> Remove my first letter and  I'll become music instead
>
> Switch my middle letters and I'm used as a cover
>
> Leave me as a cover then take away my last letter, I'll become something flammable like no other

What am I?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Are you...

> A Trap?? (revised from a Strap, which is a weaker answer*cough* I mean it doesn't work.)

Reasoning:

> "Be careful I'm dangerous, left how I'm read" 
>  Traps are generally dangerous.
>  "Remove my first letter and I'll become music instead" 
> Rap is a type of music.
>  "Switch my middle letters and I'm used as a cover" 
> Tarp, short for Tarpaulin, is used as a cover.
>  "Leave me as a cover then take away my last letter, I'll become something flammable like no other" 
> Tar is very flammable.

Method:

> Looked up types of music, found [this](http://www.musicgenreslist.com/), used brute force.

Comment: I beleive you don't need the 's' in your answer. It works fine without it as well.

Comment: If you are reading this before my 50 edits please disregard my utter stupidity.

Comment: Ah, you've edited it! Now it looks much better ;)

Comment: @greenturtle3141, correct answer!

Comment: Wait did I actually solve something on this site omg mom get the camera!!1!